# Get the sum of all the previous td elements and save it in the last td element - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem traversing the DOM, I want to get the sum of all the `tr.item td.code td.input` elements and save it in the last `td.total_quantity` element next to the `td.code_subtotal element`. I can find them by the `input.code` element inside each row.

Here is the HTML:

```
<tr class="item">
    <td class="code" rowspan="1">
        <input type="hidden" value="1775" class="id">
        <input type="hidden" value="31031005" class="code">31031005
    </td>
    <td class="total_quantity">
        <input type="hidden" value="0.109375" class="total_quantity"><span class="replaceme">0,109</span> <!-- GET THIS VALUE -->
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="item">
    <td class="code">
        <input type="hidden" value="1775" class="id">
        <input type="hidden" value="31031005" class="code">31031005
    </td>
    <td class="total_quantity">
        <input type="hidden" value="0.4176136363636363" class="total_quantity"><span class="replaceme">0,418</span> <!-- GET THIS VALUE -->
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="item">
    <td class="code_subtotal">
        <input type="hidden" value="1775" class="id">
        <input type="hidden" value="31031005" class="code">31031005
    </td>
    <td class="total_quantity"><span class="replaceme">0,136</span>
        <input type="hidden" value="HERE THE VALUE OF (input.total_quantity + input.total_quantity)" class="total_quantity"> <!-- SUM HERE THE PREVIOUS VALUES -->
    </td>
</tr>
```

I have tried this approach but it does not work:

```
      var total = 0;
      $('table#tabla_materia tr.item td.code input.code[value="31031005").each(function(index, el) {
          console.log(el.value);
          console.log('Here I'm'); // dont enter here
          total += el.parent().parent().find('td.total_quantity input.total_quantity').val();
          console.log('total : '+total );
        });
```

Also tried this approach but does not work either:

```
var total = 0;
$('table#tabla_materia tr.item td.code input.code[value="31031005"]).parent().parent().find('td.total_quantity input.total_quantity').each(function(index, el) {
      console.log('Here I'm'); // dont enter here
      total += el.value;
      // console.log('total : '+total );
    });
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you need to use `parseInt(yourValue)` - b/c what you're doing is attempting to add string values together, which isn't math. so it'd be `total += parseInt(allThatJS);`

Comment: ah ok, but the point is that I cant get the values of the previoues td elements

Comment: If you are using `[value=...]` in the selector it meansyou already know the value. Why don't you just multiply them by the number of tds? And if you didn't mean it, that may be the cause of you not getting the values

Comment: I understand, But it does not enter in the each loop. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have any way to control the HTML you're parsing, change it. The current design is horrible.

Because of the indirect relationship between elements within the table rows, you need to do multiple jQuery operations to move down and up and down the HTML.

This snippet sums all the quantity values, updates the displayed table and sets the input value you've indicated:

```js
// This is the product code (?) we're interested in
var codeval = '31031005';

// Get the quantity from each matching 'code' row in table
var inputs = $('table').find('td.code').find('input.code[value="'+codeval+'"]').parents('tr').find('span.replaceme');

// Sum the quantity values from matched rows
var quantity = 0;
for (var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
  console.log( $(inputs[i]).html() )
  // parse text e.g. 0,123 as integer
  quantity += parseInt( $(inputs[i]).html().replace(',','') );
}
console.log( quantity );

// Store total quantity in 'total_quantity' row
$('table').find('td.code_subtotal').find('input.code[value="'+codeval+'"]').parents('tr').find('input.total_quantity').val(quantity);
$('table').find('td.code_subtotal').find('input.code[value="'+codeval+'"]').parents('tr').find('span.replaceme').html(quantity);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr class="item">
    <td class="code" rowspan="1">
        <input type="hidden" value="1775" class="id">
        <input type="hidden" value="31031005" class="code">31031005
    </td>
    <td class="total_quantity">
        <input type="hidden" value="0.109375" class="total_quantity"><span class="replaceme">0,109</span> <!-- GET THIS VALUE -->
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="item">
    <td class="code">
        <input type="hidden" value="1775" class="id">
        <input type="hidden" value="31031005" class="code">31031005
    </td>
    <td class="total_quantity">
        <input type="hidden" value="0.4176136363636363" class="total_quantity"><span class="replaceme">0,418</span> <!-- GET THIS VALUE -->
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="item">
    <td class="code_subtotal">
        <input type="hidden" value="1775" class="id">
        <input type="hidden" value="31031005" class="code">31031005
    </td>
    <td class="total_quantity"><span class="replaceme">0,136</span>
        <input type="hidden" value="HERE THE VALUE OF (input.total_quantity + input.total_quantity)" class="total_quantity"> <!-- SUM HERE THE PREVIOUS VALUES -->
    </td>
</tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: I undestang, but I have a lot of td.code elements and i want only the ones that have inside a specific input.code with a specific value. that's why i ask for input.code[value=] and then go outside them

Comment: Oh - in that case, your question is really not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Rob Scott said everything, you're adding html tag 'value' which are *not* mathematical value.

By the way, i don't know how many td do you have, but if your table is big / would be one day, you better use a classic for loop rather than .each

(source: http://www.sitepoint.com/speed-question-jquery-each-vs-loop/ )

edit (after your comment) : does your console.log display the value you want to add ? If it is, it means you do have access to them by your el.value. So you just have to replace total += el.value by total += parseInt(el.value)

Comment: No, it does not enter in the each loop. I added a console.log('Here I'm') inside the each loop but it does not enter in the both ways I specified on top

Comment: Didn't see your other comment. sorry.
Could you explain why you're using `+element.Motion.code+` ? I don't get it, `input.code`should be enough

Comment: element.Motion.code it's a variable that has the value of the input.code element that i want. It;s a variable

Comment: i think i got it. You don't want to SUM all the value, but to COUNT the number of occurences of ONE specific value - passed in your variable- 

Am I right ? if yes, i agree with Mogsdad, you should just select by using `"input.code[value='yourVariableHere']"` 

Otherwise, if you really want to SUM all your td's code, I really don't get why you select them by their code - that means you already know what you want to sum, doesn't have any sense

Comment: That's right, but the problem is that the values are not in the td.code input.code element it's in the td.total_quantity that is next to the td.code input.code element. That;s why I cannot just SUM all the input.code element because the values are not there

Comment: Okay, finally got it. You should probably move your comment - "GET THIS VALUE" - up the line instead of right, I didn't see it and i think i'm not the only one.

Did you try to access the value like this ?
`$('input.code[value="'+yourCode+'"]').parent().next().children('input').val()` ? it should work. Notice that if your `td.total_quantity` is not always the next sibling of you input.code's parent, you should use `.siblings()` instead of `.next()` in the expression above